# Immediate runtime error with Tensorflow C api on M1 Mac

Tags: c++, c, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-c++

I am trying to use the Tensorflow C api in an xcode project. As soon as the app starts running a BAD_INSTRUCTION error is generated on the main thread. This error comes from:

> tensorflow::monitoring::MetricDef<(tensorflow::monitoring::MetricKind)1, long long, 2>::MetricDef<char [11], char [7]>(absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view, absl::lts_2020_02_25::string_view, char const (&) [11], char const (&) [7]) ()

I installed the api using: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c

I am building for x86_64 architectures (Using Rosetta to translate) and linked the library through specifying a runpath search path to the .dylib's directory. I also included this path as a regular search path and added the header search path too. Finally, I added both .dylibs to the 'link binary with libraries' list.

I am running xcode 12.4 on a M1 macbook pro. If anyone knows any way to get more information about the crash out of xcode that'd be useful too.

I have tried installing on an intel MacBook and that worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The M1 processor is ARM.

You compiled for x86_64 (Intel architecture) this means, that it isn't compatible.

You'd have to compile it for ARM, otherwise it won't run. (That's like trying to run JVM Bytecode in .NET, it just won't work)

For more information, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65771710/13912132)

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to mention that the app is building for x86_64. Xcode is using Rosetta to translate.

Comment: Ok, I'm no expert in tensorflow, but try to compile for as many architectures as possible. (You know, that instead of using AVX and other fancy instruction sets) try to compile only for generic processors.

Comment: It could be possible, that your x86_64 processor/rosetta just doesn't support some instructions or rosetta generates invalid machine code for you. @KingWallmo

Comment: Ok, the problem is is that the tensorflow C api is only downloadable on mac for x86_64 here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c I am currently trying to build from source to see if that helps. So are you saying Rosetta is translating but the processor still isn't able to understand?

Comment: @KingWallmo Sort of. I mean, that Rosetta either decodes the instructions from your x86 binary wrong or translates your instructions to bad M1/ARM instructions