# Using non-macOS version of tensorflow on mac m1

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, apple-m1

I recently purchased a new mac laptop with the M1 core. I've previously done work using tensorflow, and am trying to continue with my new laptop. I'm aware that apple has a tensorflow_macos version of tensorflow, but unfortunately for my project I need higher order derivatives, which the fork is not currently capable of doing. Is there a way to run the non_mac specific version of tensorflow on a M1?

If I attempt to import tensorflow from an arm terminal, I get the error:

```
python3
import tensorflow
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3
```

The same happens if I run from a Rosetta terminal.

I've also tried running from PyCharm (with a Python 3.8 virtual environment), but I receive a different problem on trying to import tensorflow:

```
Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
```

I have python3.8.5 installed. I've seen on other related questions that there should be two versions of python3 installed by default on mac (arm and x86_64), but it looks like I only have one version:

```
file $(which python3)
/Users/xxx/opt/miniconda3/bin/python3: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

I'm inexperienced when it comes to handling different core architectures, so any advice would be appreciated. I'm happy to provide clarification for any specifics.

Comment: Just so you know, your test of whether you have multiple `python3` installed is flawed -- `which` always only returns the first match found in your `PATH`. You should use `type -a python3`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up. Using that command shows python installed at two locations, one in usr/bin and the other in miniconda, which I've installed previously. Is there a way to determine if there is a arm version of python 3 installed on my device?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python3 install of Tensorflow on Apple silicon M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770132/python3-install-of-tensorflow-on-apple-silicon-m1)

Comment: Does the above reference help you?